# The Business Data Connectivity Metadata Store is currently unavailable (Only from SPD 2010)

Tags: sharepoint, bcs

I'd appreciate any help with this as I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days...

I get this error: "The business Data Connectivity Metadata Store is currently unavailable." when I click on the Object External Content Types in SharePoint Designer 2010.

What's strange is I can access external content types to create lists in SharePoint via the browser just fine.  I've tried installing the hot fix, checked permissions on the service application, metadata store, deleted the service app and recreated it, verified that proxy/services are running, and I'm a farm admin.  Tried installing SPD 2010 on a different machine, same error.

If I click through the popup, then click on the New External Content Type, I'll get this error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.  Everything else in SPD works fine.

I just don't understand where this access denied could be coming from.  My setup looks something like:

Network load balanced WFEs

Index/Search Server

Central Admin server (BCS running)

Failover clustered SQL servers

Would much appreciate any assistance with this, as I've googled far and wide...

Answer (score 0):

Does the url of the website you're connecting to happen to start with https? If so, try http instead

I encountered the same issue recently and the HTTPS was the problem

Comment: In fact, the URL does start with HTTPS.  But with the way security is configured, I am unable to reach the site with just HTTP.  Though, I do suspect the HTTPS has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your server name has underscore '_'. If it has then rename it or connect via localhost

This does not work from SPD: http://server_name

This will work: http://localhost:9009